# Replace text in column if matches specific pattern in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have the following column in a data frame:

`df$column <- c("store", "the store", "factory", "factory A")`

I want to search for an occurrence of `'store'` in `df$column` if we find a row that contains `'store'` then replace it with `'store'`. So if we come across `'the store'` it should be replaced with `'store'` because `'store'` is contained in this instance.

So a resulting output would be:

`"store", "store", "factory", "factory A"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep`: `df$column[grep("store", df$column)] <- "store"`